# Access has Many via foreach in computed property in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So I've got a hasMany defined as so
quests: DS.hasMany('quest')
I have a property that is supposed to go through each quest and work out the total.
The function looks like this,

```
questXP: function() {
    var amount = 0;

    this.get('quests').forEach(function(item)
    {
        console.log(item.get('xpReward'));
        amount += parseInt(item.get('xpReward'));
    });
    return amount;
}.property('quests'),
```

I've tried adding async: true to the hasMany but it stops the forEach from working at all. At the moment it loops 3 times(I have 3 quests) but it isn't able to access any of the quest's properties.
My thought is it's related to the fact that the quests are still being loaded.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computed property depends of each `xpReward` property. So you need to use `quests.@each.xpReward` istead of `quests`.

```
questXP: function() {
    var amount = 0;

    this.get('quests').forEach(function(item)
    {
        console.log(item.get('xpReward'));
        amount += parseInt(item.get('xpReward'));
    });
    return amount;
}.property('quests.@each.xpReward'),
```